# Приведение примитивов

Tags: java

вроде как целые литералы рассматриваются компилятором как int, а вещественные рассматриваются как double. Во второй строчке понятно почему компилятор ругается -я пытаюсь сузить 4.0 (double) к float. Однако я не понимаю почему компилятор пропускает первую строку, ведь я делаю тоже самое - пытаюсь сузить 20 (который int) к byte.

```
byte a=20;
float f=4.0; //ошибка компиляции
```

это проявляется позже:

```
byte a=50,b=20,c;
c=a+b;//не компилируется
```

Почему byte я могу назначить int без принудительного сужения ? и почему вылазит ошибка при складывании двух byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, про `byte`. Вы не можете назначить переменной типа `byte` значение, выходящее за пределы интервала (-128..127). Попробуйте присвоить `byte a = 150;`, и получите ошибку компиляции. Выражение `byte a = 50;` компилируется лишь потому, что на стадиии компиляции видно, что литерал `50` входит в диапазон `byte`.

Во-вторых, присвоить переменной типа `byte` значение, полученное путём сложения значений двух переменных типа `byte` вы не можете, потому что в общем случае значение суммы может выходить за пределы диапазона `byte`. Поэтому сложение переменных типа `byte` даёт `int`. При этом сложение литералов может дать `byte`, если результат не выходит за пределы диапазона.

В-третьих, `4.0` это литерал типа `double`. В Java автоматическое приведение к типам с меньшей точностью не предусмотрено, поэтому присваивание `float f = 4.0;` вызывает ошибку компиляции. Вам нужно либо вручную привести `4.0` к типу `float` (при помощи конструкции `float f = (float) 4.0;`), либо использовать литерал для `float`: `float f = 4.0f;`.

Подытоживая вышесказанное: Java никогда автоматически не приведёт к типу с меньшей точностью.

Comment: спасибо очень сильно разжевал!! :)

Answer (score 4):

> Почему byte я могу назначить int без принудительного сужения ?

потому, что компилятор может проверить, что переполнения не будет. Попробуйте написать `byte a = 300;`. Компилятор ругнется.

> и почему вылазит ошибка при складывании двух byte?

потому, что результат сложения двух byte будет int. Причины этого видимо в том, что компилятор не может проверить результат и перестраховывается.